# Accessing and Validating Response Values from API Platform API in Symfony Custom Validators

Tags: php, symfony, validation

I am trying to pass the response value from API Platform and create a Custom Validator to check each property in the Entity with the validator. However, the $value in the Validator always refers to the value stored in the database, rather than the value I received through the API, which is the value I want to validate.

Here is an example of how the properties in the Entity look:

```
    #[ORM\Column]
    #[CustomTestValidator(['property' => 'status'])]
    private ?float $status = null;
```

CustomTest.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Validator;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;

#[\Attribute(\Attribute::TARGET_PROPERTY | \Attribute::TARGET_METHOD | \Attribute::IS_REPEATABLE)]
class CustomTest extends Constraint
{

    public $property;
    public $permissionMessage = 'You do not have permission to modify the "{{ property }}" property.';
    public $noValuesSet = 'No values received.';
}
```

CustomTestValidator.php:

```
.... 


    public function validate($value, Constraint $constraint, )
    {
        /* @var App\Validator\CustomTest $constraint */
        dd($value); // returns the value stored in the database.
    }
....
```

It's always passing the actual value stored in the database, instead of the response.

And i want to use that validator on multiple properties in the Entity. Is there a option to receive them with property names instead of pure value(of one property)
e.g.
`['property1' => 'value1', 'property2' => 'value2'....]`

**//Edit**

I will provide an example for better understanding. I am currently running an API request using the PATCH method, with the endpoint /api/test/{test-id}. The request body includes the field "status", which has a value of 2. However, the current value stored in the database for the "status" field is 1.

In my validation function, I receive the value of the "status" field from the database, which has already been validated, but i wanted the received.